# How to default today's date in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a label inside gridview and would like to default the value of DT to today's date.  I want to show like this in the gridview 2015-02-17 . Here is the aspx for the label inside gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Date">
       <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DT")%>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind to bind gridview

```
private void Bind_GV_Test()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                string strQuery = "select ID, Name, Location,  DT from myTable ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    gv_Test.DataSource = dt;
                    gv_Test.DataBind();
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you aware that many of the technologies you are using are totally obsolete? You should not be learning them.

Comment: @usr I wouldn't say they are obsolete...

Comment: So you want to use `DateTime.Today` if the date is `NULL`?

Comment: @DavidG he seems to be a beginner learning this stuff. Nobody should be learning this in 2015.

Comment: @usr It may be something forced upon him, working on legacy code is fairly common and not everyone has the luxury of being able to use MVC, EF or any other sexy stuff!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to use [`GETDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) if it's `NULL`:

```
string strQuery = @"SELECT ID, 
                           Name, 
                           Location,  
                           DT = ISNULL(DT, GETDATE()) 
                    FROM dbo.myTable";
```

If you only want to show the date part use

```
Text='<%# Bind("DT", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'
```

or (to force the current culture's date format)

```
Text='<%# Bind("DT", "{0:d}") %>'
```

Answer (score 5):

Why go to the DB server to find out todays date?

```
<div ID="Label1"><%=DateTime.Now.Date%></div>
```

Comment: maybe DT can have a date or be null?

Comment: Don't forget the `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` to format how he wants.  I may have screwed up which one is capitalized, I always forget without looking it up.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` <> `DateTime.Today`, i also think that OP wants to use it only if the DB value is null (_"like to default the value of DT to today's date"_).

Comment: Bill, it is not showing the date value but rather it is showing this: <%=DateTime.Now%> after i run it

Comment: @moe Sorry, not sure about the asp.net controls. I rarely use them. Edit made to turn it into just a run of the mill DIV, and also to strip off the time. You can format that however you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

If the value can be `null` then:

`select ID, Name, Location,  COALESCE(DT, getdate()) AS DT from myTable`

Comment: @Chirag Chirag: please stop editing my answer, it is a working solution and clearly has merit by virtue of the upvotes. If you want to post an answer of your own and expand on why ISNULL is better than COALESCE than this will provide a better source of reference for the general community. If my answer is of course incorrect then please feel free to comment so I can take appropriate action. But please, this is the answer I wanted to post.

Answer (score 1):

Another option without having to change your query (and assuming you want to replace a null date with today's date):

```
Text='<%# string.Format(
              "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
              string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DT").ToString()) ?
                  DateTime.Today : Eval("DT")) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql command to

```
string strQuery = "select ID, Name, Location, getdate() as  DT from myTable ";
```

DT will be current datetime.